# How to exclude last 3 id and extract content from databse in mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I need to extract the latest 3 posts (with content) in upper part and rest (only heading) in the lower part from the same table. I have extracted three latest posts in the upper part. But in the lower part, headings of upper part is also repeated. I don't need to display the heading of upper part. My code goes like this:

### CODE FOR UPPER PART

```
    $fetch_sql = "SELECT fld_news_id, fld_news_name, fld_news_details FROM table_news ORDER BY fld_news_id DESC LIMIT 3";
    $fetch_result= mysql_query($fetch_sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($fetch_row=mysql_fetch_array($fetch_result))
    {
    $fld_news_id = $fetch_row['fld_news_id'];
    $fld_news_name = $fetch_row['fld_news_name'];
    $fld_news_details = $fetch_row['fld_news_details'];
    echo"<h3>  $fld_news_name </h3>";
    echo"$fld_news_details";
    }
```

### CODE FOR THE LOWER PART

```
    $fetch_sql = "SELECT fld_news_id, fld_news_name FROM table_news ORDER BY fld_news_id DESC LIMIT 10";
    $fetch_result= mysql_query($fetch_sql) or die(mysql_error()); 
    while($fetch_row=mysql_fetch_array($fetch_result))
    {
    $fld_news_id = $fetch_row['fld_news_id'];
    $fld_news_name = $fetch_row['fld_news_name'];
    echo"<h3>  $fld_news_name </h3>";
    }
```

Comment: in lower part query define row index from which to select 10 records.i.e LIMIT 3,10

Comment: Yes, it worked. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

Use following query in lower part:

```
SELECT fld_news_id, 
       fld_news_name 
FROM   table_news 
WHERE  fld_new_id NOT IN(SELECT * 
                         FROM   (SELECT fld_news_id 
                                 FROM   table_news 
                                 LIMIT  3) AS t) 
ORDER  BY fld_news_id DESC 
LIMIT  10
```

> **Description:** I am excluding result of first query from second.

Comment: it didn't work it outputs this message "This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'"